# img.onerror does not seem to work for IE8

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, internet-explorer-8, dojo

I am trying to load an image from a url to check internet connectivity. When no internet connection, it should display a dojo warning dialog. This works for Firefox but does not for IE8.

Following is the code snippet:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = userGuideUrl1_img + '?' + (new Date).getTime();
img.onload = function() {
        window.open(userGuideUrl1);
}
img.onerror = function() {
    dojo.addOnLoad(warningDialogFunc);
}
```

Here warningDialogFunc is a dojo object. Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the page is already loaded by the time the img.onerror handler is executed, and IE doesn't rexecute the function for the `dojo.addOnLoad(warningDialogFunc)`?

Try changing

```
img.onerror = function() {
    dojo.addOnLoad(warningDialogFunc);
}
```

to simply:

```
img.onerror = function() {
  warningDialogFunc();
}
```

Comment: I tried changing dojo.addOnLoad(...) entirely to simply alert('no connection'), which is a function call. That didn't make any difference. I believe that img.onerror is either not understood by IE or I am missing something else.

Comment: Figured out the problem...In order to simulate no internet connectivity, I was clicking "Work Offline" from File menu. IE's behavior is different than Firefox's in this case and it didn't work when I did this. Therefore, instead of "Working Offline" I pulled out my ethernet cable from my desktop, and then tried it; it worked.

Comment: FWIW, calls to `addOnLoad` will still fire, even if they're queued after the DOM is ready and modules have loaded.  In that case they'll just fire immediately.

Comment: Ah that would make sense.  I wasn't sure if IE did something wonky compared to other browsers with respect to onLoad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the handler before you set the source of image, when you change the src attribute, IE will try to download the image and trigger the events.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
        window.open(userGuideUrl1);
}
img.onerror = function() {
    dojo.addOnLoad(warningDialogFunc);
}
img.src = userGuideUrl1_img + '?' + (new Date).getTime();  // Trigger image download and the handlers.
```